# Зачем нужны классы в Swift

Tags: swift

Изучая `Swift` я наткнулся на `class` и не нашел применение `class` 
подскажите где их применять! (Примеры)

Comment: Я знаю что в самом классе используются значения и их нельзя использовать вне класса ЗАЧЕМ ТОГДА НУЖЕН КЛАСС?

Comment: @MioMelliot Если отвечать в лоб - то подобные "ограничения" нужны, чтоб порядок был. А если не в лоб, то можно много рассказать о том, что кроме значений в классах еще иметоды. А еще о том, что использование классов - это не только их создание, но и работа с готовыми, а от них никуда не денешься, не писать же все на CoreFoundation только из-за фобии к классам. Много можно рассказать, но вы подумайте над моим предложением лучше.

Comment: @Mio https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В языке `Swift` (да и вроде в любом другом) -

Классы и структуры являются универсальными и гибкими конструкциями, которые станут строительными блоками для кода вашей программы. Для добавления функциональности в классах и структурах можно объявить свойства и методы, применив тот же синтаксис, как и и при объявлении констант, переменных и функций.

***Пример:***

```
class Shape {
    var numberOfSides = 0
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }
}
```

Если простыми словами - легче создавать обьекты и выстраивать логику между этими обьектами...

[Стоит почитать](https://swiftbook.ru/content/classes-and-structures/)

*Надеюсь помог!*

Comment: Есть ли правила образования class?

Comment: @MioMelliot Правила как "_хороший тон_", или правила как "_Реализация_"?

Comment: Правила как "реализация"

Comment: @MioMelliot Я же прикладывал [Ссылку на примеры и способы реализации классов](http://swiftbook.ru/doc/swift-tour/objects-and-classes)

Comment: Ну я её прочетал

Comment: @MioMelliot Там и указанны "правила" реализации классов

Comment: Ладно пересмотрю ещё раз :)

Comment: А как применять class примеры